# depth_registered

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I get depth_registered from the Kinect and what topic should I use ?

and It is the same imageCallback as depth (/camera/depth/image)?

```
void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
{

    cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;

    try
    {
        cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg1, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::TYPE_32FC1);
    }

    catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
    {
        ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
        return;
    }


    cv::imshow("OpenCV viewer Kinect ", cv_ptr->image);

    cvWaitKey(3);

}
```

I tried this ones:

/camera/depth_registered/points

/camera/depth_registered/image_raw

but I didn't get any resulat.
so what should I do ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186749/depth_registered/) by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 751 on 2014-07-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

/camera/depth_registered/points publishes point clouds and not Image.

You can convert it from a `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2` to a `pcl::PointCloud <pcl::PointXYZRGB>` data type.

Are you using openni.launch from openni_launch pkg?

If yes, the topic /camera/depth_registered/image_raw should work for you.

You can learn the type of the topic by using -

```
rostopic type <topic name>
```

If I remember correctly there is an 'arg' called depth_registration that should be set to true if you want depth registration to be available. I am not exactly sure. Please check openni.launch file and try setting it to true if it is false.

Though this seems off-topic, this provides some useful info on the different topics http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch/Tutorials/BagRecordingPlayback

---

Originally posted by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) with karma: 1247 on 2014-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-07-16**:
very usefull answer, I can subscribe to the topic but I get something like that:

https://www.mediafire.com/?y3das9c4mcadjm9

What does it mean this ?

I'm converting the data that I get from the kinect from float to 8UC.

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-07-16**:
What do you intend to do with your data? Why do you need point cloud data?

Please update your question and tell how exactly you solved it. It will be useful for others to see how you solved it. Please point out the exact mistake and the remedy.

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-07-16**:
And accept an answer that solves the issue, because that way others can rely on the answer if they have the same problem.

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-07-16**:
So the main solution is to launch the kinect command with a parameter like that:
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch depth_registration:=true
and then you can subscribe to the topic normally. That's it.